# Is there a way to get more than one intent (and their related scores) as a result when using AWS LEX?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nlp, chatbot, azure-language-understanding, amazon-lex

When calling the AWS LEX API (put-text) or even when we are testing the bot by using the AWS Console, we receive only one intent as the output that matches our input.

However, for the feature that we are building, we would like to see not only the intent that best fits our input, but also some other intents that could be related with a lower score.

Ideally, we would also want to get the score for each one of the intents.

We know that this is something that is possible with Azure LUIS, but we are trying to develop this by using AWS.

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Lex does not provide this functionality. You should try out LUIS or RASA.